# Why did bootstrap 3 make all my fonts smaller?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I am new to bootstrap, and I added bootstrap 3 into my project and it shrunk all the font sizes, I never had any font size specified in these classes.  I thought bootstrap 3 had the default size to 14.. is there something else I need to do?

Thanks

Answer (score -4, accepted):

You can customize/override anything - if, for example, you load YOUR css file AFTER the bootstrap file, then your settings will override it.  Whatever you can dream:

```
p {
  font-size 18px;
}
```

and so on...

I strongly recommend digging into the source code: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/dist/css/bootstrap.css

```
html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

body {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.428571429;
  color: #333333;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

UPDATE: TO clarify, "No" you shouldn't have to do anything else. It sounds like there is another problem.  The linked source code has changed since the original answer date... as of Feb 2015, it looks like this:

```
html {
  font-size: 10px;
}
body {
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

Assuming we've set our project up correctly, (`bower install bootstrap` is pretty easy)... attempting to echo text outside of the `body` should result in 10px text, inside `body` should be 14px.

If you don't see 14 point text inside the body, then something else might be stepping on it.  I'd next inspect in in Chrome (for example) to confirm where the font-size was coming from.

I'd like to add that I think it's helpful to understand how these values we see in this /dist/css file are derived from less variables... the defaults should work out of the box, but you have easy control over everything, including the body text size: see http://getbootstrap.com/css/#less-variables.

Comment: Thanks for that, do you recommend putting the bootstrap.css file first? that way like you said you can override whatever you want with your own css?

Comment: you can even do both... "before.css", then bootstrap.css, then after.css - even better, check out using less

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.  I had the same issue and was confused as to why my fonts are so small with the latest bootstrap.  I don't want to have to override the defaults and I can't use rem units with a weirdly small bootrap root font-size.  What gives?

Answer (score 18):

It appears to be happening, at least as of version 3.3.6, due to this block on line 1097:

```
html {
  font-size: 10px;

  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

You can restore your font-size by adding this to your stylesheet:

```
html
{
    font-size: 100%;
}
```

Comment: This is the solutions that worked for me. I'm adding bootstrap to the Twenty Seventeen Child Theme. Thanks!